# Getline with g++ and gcc

Tags: c, gcc, g++, malloc, getline

sorry if it's already here somewhere, i didn't find it.

My simple program is:

```
int main(){

size_t n = 0;

char *line = NULL;

getline(&line,&n,stdin);

free(line);

return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==7300== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7300==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==7300==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 72,824 bytes allocated
==7300==
```

I need to compile using `g++ -g -o -Wall -pedantic`. When i compile using `gcc`, problem disappears.

I'd like to ask why getline allocates 2 blocks of memory and how to free the other one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you get the same output if you comment out the `getline` call?

Comment: ==8417== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8417==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==8417==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 72,704 bytes allocated

Comment: I don't think `getline()` is responsible, don't use it in c++ anyway.

Comment: OK, so `getline` actually has nothing to do with the problem. Maybe delete this question

Comment: Also, I am unable to reproduce it. Please check that you have valgrind installed correctly, it comes with a set of predefined suppressions and you might be missing one of them.

Comment: Where is the prototype/declaration for `getline(&line,&n,stdin);` and `size_t`?   I'd expect a `#include ...` or two before `main()`.

Comment: This problem was caused by gcc version 5, which is kinda buggy. Update to version 6 helped. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was caused by gcc version 5, which is kinda buggy. Update to version 6 helped. – Cart